# NoClassDefFoundException when using javax.tools package

Tags: android, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror

I'm developing an android app in eclipse and am having some trouble importing some libraries into my build. Specifically, I'm using some classes in the javax.tools package, which is included in the jre7 system library. For some reason it isn't available during runtime, even though I've told the library to export to the build path.

I've tried to isolate the package I need and adding them as an external .jar as was suggested on some android/stackoverflow forums but I was having trouble with that. Considering the package is part of the standard java library, is there an easier way to include it in the final build?

Thanks, I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

The standard Java library is a little bit different from android Java library. In eclipse preferences -> Java build path -> Order and Export -> tick the check box of your external jar, compile and build again.

Comment: Hey yushulx, I've tried adding my external library as you described and as it was detailed on the other forums. I'd rather just use the jre7 system library though, is there a way to do this? When I check the box for this library under exports it still can't find it during runtime

Comment: Have you moved this library to top?

Comment: Yep, I've tried that but I still get the NoClassDefFoundError for classes included in that library when they're called at runtime. Any idea why the JRE System Library's classes aren't being exported to the build path even though the library's been checked and ordered first?